# Plotly and d3.js drag shape

Tags: python, d3.js, plotly, plotly-python

I want to allow the user to drag shapes in Plotly, but restrict this to horizontal movement only. Therefore, I am using d3.js for the drag behavior. Everything works nicely except that, when a user clicks a shape, apparently Plotly rewrites the  objects for all shapes -- which deletes all my modifications, hence removing the ability to drag.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open `plotly_output.html` in browser.
2. Drag and drop one of the shapes: it works fine.
3. Click one of the shapes: it returns to its original place (bad!). If you look at `.cartesianlayer .shapelayer` in the console, it gets rewritten.
4. Draging and dropping no longer works.

## Code:

`poltly_tmk.py`

```py
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
y = x ** 3
fig = px.scatter(x=x, y=y)

bottom_edge = 0

i = 20
point_x, point_y = x[i], y[i]
fig.add_shape(x0=point_x, x1=point_x + .1, y0=bottom_edge, y1=point_y, fillcolor='blue', layer='below', line=dict(width=0))

i = 40
point_x, point_y = x[i], y[i]
fig.add_shape(x0=point_x, x1=point_x + .1, y0=bottom_edge, y1=point_y, fillcolor='yellow', layer='below', line=dict(width=0))

extrajs = '''
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script src='plotly.js'></script>
'''

style = '''
<style>.cartesianlayer .shapelayer path {
    pointer-events: all;
}</style>
'''

layout = dict(dragmode=False)
fig.update_layout(layout)

config = {"modeBarButtonsToRemove": ['zoom2d']}
html = plotly.io.to_html(fig, full_html=False, config=config)
with open('plotly_output.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html + extrajs + style)
```

`plotly.js`

```js
for (const node of d3.selectAll('.shapelayer path').nodes()) {
    d3.select(node)
        .datum({x: 0})
        .call(d3.drag()
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on('end',dragended))
}

function dragged(event,d) {
    d3.select(this)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (d.x = event.x) + "," + 0 + ")")
}

function dragended(event,d){
    console.log(event.x)
}
```